# Where can I find the igraph layout source code?

Tags: python, igraph

I've been looking all over ([igraph-python docs](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/index.html), the [c reference manual](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch18s01.html#igraph_layout_kamada_kawai)) and I can't seem to find a trace of the code in the python-igraph module for the various layout algorithms used.

In iPython I can do `Graph.layout_kamada_kawai?` and `Graph.layout_kamada_kawai??`. The former gives me a C-like docstring, while the latter gives me a couple lines of code in `__init__.py` that is most definitely not the layout algorithm.

If the code for these algorithms (specifically `kamada_kawai`) is in the C core distribution, if you could point me to the source code directories, that'd be great as well. I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python-igraph is just a wrapper to the igraph C library, and all the sources are on github. The layout algorithms you are looking for are here:
https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/master/src/layout.c

Actually, some of them, e.g. the Kamada-Kawai was just rewritten in the development version of igraph. This new version now follows the original paper completely, and it is about 100 times faster (for graphs with ~500 vertices) than the old version. It is here:
https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/develop/src/layout_kk.c

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the development version.

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found what your looking for by downloading the source code for igraph here http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-igraph/python-igraph-0.6.5.tar.gz decompressing it into a temp directory and then going to the python-igraph-0.6.5/src subdirectory in a terminal.

Doing `grep -rn layout_kamada_kawai ./` tells me theres a function called igraphmodule_Graph_layout_kamada_kawai on line 6029 and 12925 in the graphobject.c file.

Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: The issue I have is that I've looked through the source code and documentation but still can't find it.

Comment: I was pocking around and it appears the core of graph is written in C++ (http://igraph.wikidot.com). Have you tried downloading the source code at http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-igraph/python-igraph-0.6.5.tar.gz.  Sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Ron: igraph is a C library, and python-igraph is a wrapper to it. The C library is not included in the wrapper, so the sources the OP is looking for, will not be in the pypi package.